# Where is "this.props.routes" in react-router v4 & 5?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, breadcrumbs

I am trying to upgrade from react-router v3.0.5 to v5.0.0. I have a lot to tackle, one being the breadcrumbs.

My project uses react-breadcrumbs v1.6.6, which expects a "routes" prop. In react-router v3.x, you have "routes" in props, if the component is wrapped with `<Router>`. So you can instantiate Breadcrumbs like that:

```
<Breadcrumbs
  routes={this.props.routes}
  location={this.props.location}
  params={this.props.params}
/>
```

But in react-router v5.0.0, I can't find "routes" in props. Is there a way to get these "routes" props? I don't want to upgrade to Breadcrumbs v2.1.6, which doesn't seem to be backwards compatible.

Comment: You could create a dedicated [`CrumbRoute` component like in the documentation](https://github.com/svenanders/react-breadcrumbs/blob/38a0b2ff79208f7019b30d5b610ab8a9e1a8dc12/demo/src/crumb-route.jsx) for newer versions of React Router.

Comment: @Tholle, yes, for v2.1.6. I will consider upgrading to v2.1.6 as a last resort.